# CMD Parse within http address

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I write a batch file for my project. I like to go through my svn-http-address, so I could find out if I'm working on a branch or in trunk. And as well the branch name is of interest.

The paths which I will search in look like:

- https://aaa.com/bbb/ccc/ddd/trunk/
- https://aaa.com/bbb/ccc/ddd/branches/thebranchname

I tried with "for" and "%variable:StrToFind=NewStr%" commandos. But I end up in problems with the "/", ":" characters.

Any ideas how I can solve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: How to distinguish? "`trunk`" vs. "`branches`"? are those fixed strings?

Comment: "trunk" and "branches" are fix strings and it would be possible to parse for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quite straightforward:

```
@ECHO OFF 

set "adress=https://aaa.com/bbb/ccc/ddd/trunk/"
call :Where %adress%

set "adress=https://aaa.com/bbb/ccc/ddd/branches/thebranchname"
call :Where %adress%

set "adress=https://aaa.com/bbb/ccc/ddd/neither/thebranchname"
call :Where %adress%

goto :eof

:Where
echo address: %adress%
echo %1|find /i "/trunk">nul && (echo I'm in Trunk & goto :eof)
echo %1|find /i "/branches">nul || (echo neither trunk nor branches & goto :eof)
set "branchname=%adress:*branches/=%"
echo I'm working for %branchname%
goto :eof
```

Answer (score 1):

> I tried with "for" and "%variable:StrToFind=NewStr%" commandos.

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
SETLOCAL enableextensions
set "_addr1=https://aaa.com/bbb/ccc/ddd/trunk/"
set "_addr2=%_addr1:trunk=branches/thebranchname%"

set "_adold=trunk/"
set "_adnew=branches/thebranchname"
call set "_addr3=%%_addr1:%_adold%=%_adnew%%%"
rem from cmd: (note %s vs. %%s) call set "_addr3=%_addr1:%_adold%=%_adnew%%"
rem with enabledelayedexpansion call set "_addr3=!_addr1:%_adold%=%_adnew%!"
set _
```

**Output**:

```
==>set _ad
Environment variable _ad not defined

==>D:\bat\SO\31209302.bat
_addr1=https://aaa.com/bbb/ccc/ddd/trunk/
_addr2=https://aaa.com/bbb/ccc/ddd/branches/thebranchname/
_addr3=https://aaa.com/bbb/ccc/ddd/branches/thebranchname
_adnew=branches/thebranchname
_adold=trunk/

==>
```